# Better use of pattern matching in replacing elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, replacement, conditional

I have a list of reals and I'm replacing those which are contained in a given interval with two different values depending on wheter the selected reals are positive or negative.

I came up with this (overly convoluted) code:

```
list = {-2., -1.6, -1.2, -0.8, -0.4, 0., 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.}

list /. MapThread[#2 -> #1 &, {If[TrueQ[#], 1, -1] & /@ Positive /@ #, #}]&@Cases[list, x_ /; -1 < x < 1]
```

This does the work, but I'm sure there are more efficent ways of dealing with replacing elements of a list according to multiple criteria.
My question is how could I make a better use of pattern matching to solve the problem and thus possibly shorten/simplify the code.

Edit:
Generalizing the problem, given a list of numbers, I need to:
1. Identify all the numbers between a choosen interval
2. Check which of these numbers are positive and which are negative
3. Replace each of them with one of the two new choosen values, according to their sign

Here's another example with my old code:

```
list = {-3., -2.6, -2.2, -1.8, -1.4, -1., -0.6, -0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1., 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6`, 3.}  

{min, max} = {-1.5, 3};

{newValueIfPositive, newValueIfNegative} = {50, 700};

list /. MapThread[#2 -> #1 &, {If[TrueQ[#], newValueIfPositive,newValueIfNegative] & /@ Positive /@ #, #}] &@Cases[list, x_ /; min < x < max]
```

Comment: Like this: `{-2., -1.6, -1.2, -0.8, -0.4, 0., 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.} /. x_ /; Abs[x] < 1 :> (1 - 2 UnitStep[-x])`?

Comment: Let's make it more Listable~

Comment: Why not just use two rules? `list /. {x_ /; -1 < x <= 0 -> -1, x_ /; 0 < x < 1 -> 1}`

Comment: An alternative way: `Block[{b = UnitBox[list/2]}, list + b (Sign[list] + list)]`a bit slower than @SimonWoods ' answer

Comment: @J. M.♦ Yes, that's the kind of pattern-matching style I was looking for, but I'd like to generalize the problem, thus a solution that doesn't imply the replacing values are -1 and 1 (my bad for not pointing out -1 and 1 were an example, but thanks anyway!).

Comment: @Simon Woods That works just fine and is very readable. Unfortunately I'm still inexperienced with pattern-matching and a solution so simple just didn't cross my mind. Thank you!

Comment: Then, can you edit your question to add the "general" problem you speak of?

Comment: For your general problem: `list /. x_ /; min < x < max :> Rescale[Sign[x], {-1, 1}, {700, 50}]`. But did you think about how to handle 0?

Comment: @J. M.♦ I could never come up with this solution, thank you very much. About the 0, the actual lists I'll be working with will have values very close to zero but there won't be zeros, so I didn't really think how to handle it (the list of the first example it's not from the data I'll be handling so has a 0, another inattention of mine, I'm sorry). For precaution I think I'll just  make sure to get rid of it with another rule:    list /. {0 -> Nothing,  x_ /; min < x < max :> Rescale[Sign[x],{-1,1}, {700,50}]}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
list = {-3., -2.6, -2.2, -1.8, -1.4, -1., -0.6, -0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1., 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3.};
{min, max} = {-1.5, 3};
{pos, non} = {50, 700};
```

I'd just stick with a direct expression of the requirement:

```
Replace[list, x_ /; min < x < max :> If[Positive[x], pos, non], {1}]

(*
{-3., -2.6, -2.2, -1.8, 700, 700, 700, 700, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 3.}
*)
```

This performs well enough, even for large lists, that I wouldn't bother trying to vectorize it unless a performance profile revealed that this expression is the application hot-spot.  Even then, effective optimization would require more information about the wider application context to see whether significant performance improvements are to be gained by an algorithm change as opposed to micro-optimizing this particular expression.

In the case at hand, `/.` could be used instead of `Replace[…, {1}]`:

```
list /. x_ /; min < x < max :> If[Positive[x], pos, non]
```

However, this relies upon the coincidence that when `<` is applied to lists it does not return a boolean value thus causing the pattern matcher to descend into the list elements to try further replacements.  For different conditions, the replacement operation might mistakenly attempt to transform the entire top-level expression instead of each list element individually.  Code written in this way is brittle since a seemingly innocuous change to the pattern condition can radically change the program meaning.  For that reason, I tend to use `Replace` with an explicit level specification as a defensive measure.

Answer (score 2):

A rather convoluted method to apply this transformation, without pattern matching:

```
rep[a_List, lo_, hi_, n_, p_] :=
  With[{u = Unitize @ Clip[a, {lo, hi}, {0, 0}]},
    Join[{p}, a, {n}][[(1 - u) Range[2, Length @ a + 1] + Sign[a u]]]
  ]

list = {-2., -1.6, -1.2, -0.8, -0.4, 0., 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.};

rep[list, -1, 1, neg, pos]
```

> ```
> {-2., -1.6, -1.2, neg, neg, 0., pos, pos, 1.2, 1.6, 2.}
> ```